# How to re-execute the last command which name begins with 'c' in Korn Shell (ksh)?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Just like in the title. I do not know how I can do it in Korn Shell. I tried:

```
r 'c*'
```

...with no result. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply `r c` works for me (Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 0):

Use `r c`.

Maybe r isn't aliased on your system? Should be:

```
alias r='hist -s'
```